# Subscribe multiple Angular2 components to a Service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to make two `Components` to get notified through a `Service` when another `Component` reacts to a DOM event.

This should be achieved using [RxJS Subject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html) Observable, or its direct subclasses(BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject probably).

This is the model:

- TriggerComponent
- NotificationService
- FirstListeningComponent
- SecondListeningComponent

Neither of these three components are parent-child.

I tried to follow these approaches:

1. [Angular2 Parent and Children communication via service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)
2. [RxJSObservable demo explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2#answer-35568924)

but I didn't manage to adapt them for my needs.

Please check [my live example on plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQq3mIx9rpyI1DkDKtSk?p=preview)

Am I on the right path?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed your plunker with a [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z34dTgCyyZO0fjYG75xO?p=preview) version.

The problem was that new instances of the NotificationService were created for every component. It should exist only one instance, created in the main component, and the components should share that instance to comunicate.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <br>
      <trigger-component></trigger-component>

      <first-listening-component></first-listening-component>
      <second-listening-component></second-listening-component>
    </div>
  `,
  providers : [NotificationService]
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```